# What is the difference between Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu and Lubuntu restricted extras/addons?

Tags: codecs, ubuntu-restricted-extras

While I use Lubuntu, for example, do I need ubuntu-restricted? or those of xubuntu or kubuntu? Do they add some enhancement, like supplementary media codecs, to what I have in lubuntu-restricted?

```
apt-cache search --names-only ".*ubuntu-restricted-(addons|extras)"
kubuntu-restricted-addons - Commonly used restricted packages for Kubuntu
kubuntu-restricted-extras - Commonly used restricted packages for Kubuntu
lubuntu-restricted-addons - Commonly used restricted packages for Lubuntu
lubuntu-restricted-extras - Commonly used restricted packages for Lubuntu
ubuntu-restricted-addons - Commonly used restricted packages for Ubuntu
ubuntu-restricted-extras - Commonly used restricted packages for Ubuntu
xubuntu-restricted-addons - Commonly used restricted packages for Xubuntu
xubuntu-restricted-extras - Commonly used restricted packages for Xubuntu
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### `-addons` vs `-extras`

Looking at the packages it's easy to tell these are *metapackages* - they're just depending on other packages and are empty by themselves. The only reason for their existence is to ease the user in installing a set of packages by just setting dependencies.

By [looking at the dependencies](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/kubuntu-restricted-extras) of these you can see that `-extras` is depending on `-addons`, thus making the former an extension on the latter.

The description of both packages (`apt-cache show ubuntu-restricted-addons`):

> *Commonly used restricted packages for Ubuntu*
>
> This package depends on some commonly used packages in the Ubuntu
>   universe and multiverse repositories.
>
> **You should not install this package directly, but instead install the
>   `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package.**

`apt-cache show ubuntu-restricted-extras`:

> *Commonly used restricted packages for Ubuntu*
>
> This package depends on some commonly used packages in the Ubuntu
>   multiverse repository.
>
> Installing this package will pull in support for MP3 playback and
>   decoding, support for various other audio formats (GStreamer plugins),
>   Microsoft fonts, Flash plugin, LAME (to create compressed audio
>   files), and DVD playback.
>
> Please note that this does not install libdvdcss2, and will not let
>   you play encrypted DVDs. For more information, see
>   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs
>
> Please also note that packages from multiverse are restricted by
>   copyright or legal issues in some countries. See
>   http://www.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/licensing for more information.

Now that mystery is solved, let's see what the differences are on the Ubuntu derivative part.

---

### `ubuntu-` vs `kubuntu-` vs `lubuntu-` vs `xubuntu-`

This just depends on what the derivatives have decided on to ship and recommend. Sometimes this includes Desktop Environment specific packages. Some examples:

- The dependency on `libk3b6-extracodecs` in [`kubuntu-restricted-addons`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/kubuntu-restricted-addons) is only valid for KDE as this package is for K3b (KDE disc burning application) only.
- The `lubuntu` set appears to contain a lot less dependencies and especially excluding the `gstreamer` codecs. This may indicate that LXDE's default player is not GStreamer based, and it's sane not to install all kinds of GStreamer libraries probably not being used in a Lubuntu installation.

Comment: In fact I have installed ubuntu-restricted in Lubuntu, this seems to add capabilities that otherwise would not be available