# Why can't I read encrypted DVDs after installing libdvdread4?

Tags: dvd, decryption

I have already installed `libdvdread4` and I still get the message:

> Could not read DVD. This may be because the DVD is encrypted and a DVD decryption library is not installed.

Answer (score 4):

`libdvdread4` alone is not sufficient to play DVD movie discs. For your convenience, Ubuntu includes a nice metapackage to install most libraries and codecs to watch media: [Ubuntu Restricted Extras](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-restricted-extras) [image: Install ubuntu-restricted-extras].

This does not include `libdvdcss2` from the Medibuntu repository yet. It's not included in Ubuntu for legal reasons as mentioned on the [Ubuntu Wiki: RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs). See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/13086/88802) on how to enable the Medibuntu repository and how to install this package.

In case you're still having problems playing DVDs and you have both `libdvdread4` and `libdvdcss2` installed, see this relevant question: [Why does DVD playback still not work after installing libdvdcss2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185587/why-does-dvd-playback-still-not-work-after-installing-libdvdcss2), specifically [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/187919/88802) in it about setting the region code on your DVD player.

In case you're running an official derivative of Ubuntu, this might be relevant as well:

- [What is the difference between Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu and Lubuntu restricted extras/addons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248769/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-kubuntu-xubuntu-and-lubuntu-restricted-e/248792#248792)